# ES6 String Substitution does not work

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
let fName = "Nick";
let lName = "Lee";

document.write('${fName}');
```

Output on Chrome:

${fName}

I expected it to be Nick.

Comment: Use the right symbols, read the [docs for template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'${fName}'` is treated as a regular string. You're supposed to use string templates:

```
document.write(`${fName}`);
```